my spoon transformation not works property
i have a CSV file with a transformation of the steps of imagen file.

The csv file has 9430 rows and all the steps transforms the data. The dont add or substrats rows.
in the last step, i have in 'written' 2 rows... and the 2 rows is not in the database. the 2 rows are the row 7002 and 8002.
I dont know what is going on here.
aditional info:

I have connection to the database

this etl with few steps works property in the last month. Today i add steps (4°,12°,14°)

use another computer.

close and open spoon.


